# Maximum Value taken by thief

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy

Consider we have a sacks of gold and thief wants to get the maximum gold. Thief can take the gold to get maximum by,

1) Taking the Gold from contiguous sacks.

2) Thief should take the same amount of gold from all sacks.

N Sacks 1 <= N <= 1000

M quantity of Gold 0 <= M <= 100

Sample Input1:

3 0 5 4 4 4

Output:
16

Explanation:
4 is the minimum amount he can take from the sacks 3 to 6 to get the maximum value of 16.

Sample Input2: 
2 4 3 2 1

Output:
8

Explanation:
2 is the minimum amount he can take from the sacks 1 to 4 to get the maximum value of 8.

I approached the problem using subtracting the values from array and taking the transition point from negative to positive, but this doesn't solves the problem.

EDIT: code provided by OP to find the index:

```
int temp[6]; 
for(i=1;i<6;i++){ 
    for(j=i-1; j>=0;j--) { 
        temp[j] = a[j] - a[i]; 
    } 
} 
for(i=0;i<6;i++){ 
    if(temp[i]>=0) { 
        index =i; 
        break; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't it solve the problem? What is your algorithm you have used (actual code or pseudo-code)?

Comment: Any constraints? what is the maximum number of sacks? min and max value of gold in each sack?

Comment: @AJD, please find my code to find the index,
`int temp[6];
 for(i=1;i<6;i++){
  for(j=i-1; j>=0;j--)
  {
   temp[j] = a[j] - a[i];
  }
 }
 for(i=0;i<6;i++){
  if(temp[i]>=0)
  {
   index =i;
   break;
  }
 }`

Comment: @PhamTrung, There will be no min or max value of gold in each sack. It's like, the value of gold in all the sacks are of equal, but the sack may contain different quantity of gold. We have to find the maximum quantity of gold, a thief can take from a contiguous sacks and equal quantity.

Please see the sample input and output for further clarification.

Comment: @irs102info what is the time complexity you are aiming for this problem, According to me, if you go for dp, then you will get O(n^2) as the worst case time complexity.

Comment: You seem misunderstanding my comment. I understand the problem perfectly. But if we are solving a problem with infinite/no limitation, which means the number of sacks is very large, there is no solution. No computer can solve it. A solution could only be considered reasonable under certain constraints. Without constraints, there is no reasonable solution except O(1) solution which obviously not exists

Comment: To follow up on Pham. I have a solution that will take O(n*m) where n is the number of sacks and m is the highest value in a sack. Is this of interest or is m assumed to be in the order of n?

Comment: @SaiBot If you only care about existing elements in the sacks, so there should be at most `n` unique values. Maybe that could help?

Comment: @PhamTrung, if this is the case then my algorithm will not help to bring the complexity lower than O(n*n). However if m << n then it would help. Just wanted to back up your claim that constraints matter.

Comment: @PhamTrung, Yeah, we have a constraints with n sacks and m quantity of gold in each sack. I thought i have added the constraints in the question.
Apologize for the miscommunication.

Comment: With this constraints, an O(n^2) solution with two loops, one go forward, one go backward to update the maximum possible value, will be enough. What is your difficulty?

Answer (score 3):

The best amount of gold (TBAG) taken from every sack is equal to weight of some sack. Let's put indexes of candidates in a stack in order.

When we meet heavier weight (than stack contains), it definitely continues "good sequence", so we just add its index to the stack.

When we meet lighter weight (than stack top), it breaks some "good sequences" and we can remove heavier candidates from the stack - they will not have chance to be TBAG later. Remove stack top until lighter weight is met, calculate potentially stolen sum during this process.

Note that stack always contains indexes of strictly increasing sequence of weights, so we don't need to consider items before index at the stack top (intermediate AG) in calculation of stolen sum (they will be considered later with another AG value).

```
for idx in Range(Sacks):
     while (not Stack.Empty) and (Sacks[Stack.Peek] >= Sacks[idx]): //smaller sack is met
         AG = Sacks[Stack.Pop]
         if Stack.Empty then
            firstidx = 0
         else  
            firstidx = Stack.Peek + 1
         //range_length * smallest_weight_in_range
         BestSUM = MaxValue(BestSUM, AG * (idx - firstidx))  
     Stack.Push(idx)

now check the rest: 
  repeat while loop without >= condition
```

Every item is pushed and popped once, so linear time and space complexity.

P.S. I feel that I've ever seen this problem in another formulation...

Comment: Could you please explain more about your algorithm, I messed up in traversing the algorithm.

Comment: I hoped that explained all steps. But I realize this algorithm is hard for understanding. What stage is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

I see two differents approaches for the moment :

**Naive approach:** For each pair of indices (i,j) in the array, compute the minimum value m(i,j) of the array in the interval (i,j) and then compute score(i,j) = |j-i+1|*m(i,j). Take then the maximum score over all the pairs (i,j).

-> Complexity of O(n^3).

**Less naive approach:**

1. Compute the set of values of the array
2. For each value, compute the maximum score it can get. For that, you just have to iterate once over all the values of the array. For example, when your sample input is [3 0 5 4 4 4] and the current value you are looking is 3, then it will give you a score of 12. (You'll first find a value of 3 thanks to the first index, and then a score of 12 due to indices from 2 to 5).
3. Take the maximum over all values found at step 2.

-> Complexity is here O(n*m), since you have to do at most m times the step 2, and the step 2 can be done in O(n).

Maybe there is a better complexity,  but I don't have a clue yet.