# Maximum Area Histogram Dynamic programming C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, histogram, dynamic-programming, brute-force

I was trying to get the maximum area in a histogram.

I already did that using brute force algorithm and it worked very well, But i wanna do it using Dynamic Programming.

I DONT need any codes , i just want to know the idea of writing it but using dynamic programming

Here is my bruteforce code.
Note that : Number of buildings are the number of Columns in the histogram

```
int getMaxArea(build building[], int NumOfBuildings) {

    int BuildingHeight = 0; //Height of Smallest Building of current Iteration.
    int Total_BuildingLength = 0; // Total length of current buildings iteration
    int max_area = 0; // Maximum Area Calculated
    int CurrentArea; //Store Current Area

    int i = 0;
    while (i < NumOfBuildings)
    {
        int j = i;
        BuildingHeight = building[j].height;

        while (j < NumOfBuildings) //(J)Iterate to the the last building starting from each (i) building. 
        {
            if (BuildingHeight >= building[j].height){
                BuildingHeight = building[j].height; // At Every Iteration assign new Smallest height for area calculation

            }
            // Each Step calculates Area.
            Total_BuildingLength += building[j].length;
            CurrentArea = BuildingHeight * Total_BuildingLength;

            if (max_area < CurrentArea){
                max_area = CurrentArea;
            }

            j++;
        }
        //Reset Length
        Total_BuildingLength = 0;
        i++;
    }
    return max_area; 
}
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately SO isn't the place for code reviews (if that's what you're asking). Otherwise if you have an actual issue with your implementation than make that explicit in your question.

Comment: i dont need a code , i just want the Idea of getting this area but using Dynamic programming.

Comment: [Similar problem in another formulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616925/maximum-value-taken-by-thief/48619491#48619491)